# echoing the date modified on top of the files

Tags: php

can I echo the date or date modified? on top of every csv file? I had an idea on how to do that but that didn't work out.

```
<?php

$arrFiles = glob("../Csv_folder/*.csv");
$arrSortedFiles = array();
foreach($arrFiles as $strFileName) {
   $arrSortedFiles[$strFileName] = filemtime($strFileName);
}

arsort($arrSortedFiles);
foreach(array_keys($arrSortedFiles) as $strFileName)

{
   $file_handle = fopen($strFileName, "r");  
   while (!feof($file_handle) ) {  
      $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);  
      echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td></tr>'; 
   }  
   fclose($file_handle);  
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[filemtime](http://php.net/filemtime)**

> Returns the time the file was last modified, or FALSE on failure. The time is returned as a Unix timestamp, which is suitable for the date() function.

Just before you start echoing out your file, you can do

```
echo "Time: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($strFileName));
```

And add a line break or a table row etc. as required.

**Edit**

Replace your echo with this one

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td><td>Time: '.date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($strFileName)).'</td></tr>';
```

**Edit 2**

Replace your loop with this

```
foreach(array_keys($arrSortedFiles) as $strFileName)
{
   $file_handle = fopen($strFileName, "r");  
   echo "<tr><td colspan='5'></td><td>".date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($strFileName))."</td></tr>";
   while (!feof($file_handle) ) {  
      $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);  
      echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td></tr>'; 
   }  
   fclose($file_handle);  
}
```

Comment: hmm this does give me the date. but it doesnt quite fit sinds it shows like 20-30 times. what I wanna do is that every csv file for instance is seperate from eachother and then but the date in between. this script does show every csv but as 1 table. is there a way to show them all seperatly? this is how it looks right now. http://prntscr.com/6cxf8d

Comment: Oh Come on, you can't move that echo code inside a table?

Comment: to be honest I am really a noob in php. I am trying to learn it.

Comment: Ok I respect your honestly but we are here to help you learn. Let me guide you to it instead of giving you something to copy paste so your time spent here makes you learn the language more.  You have an echo right? The one that has `<tr>` and `<td>s`? At the end of it, add another `<td>` and then that echo i gave you. You will be please with the result

Comment: *pleased*, not *please* sorry. And if it doesn't work then ill help you make it work :)

Comment: oright ok so I did this http://prntscr.com/6cxid1 and this is the result I get. http://prntscr.com/6cxids and thx u I respect u sir.

Comment: You added a new tr as well. Ok since you tried, let me update the answer. See the updated answer in a minute

Comment: ok I see what I did wrong and this is the result http://prntscr.com/6cxjtd I think this is a good step in the right direction :D.

Comment: Is there still a way to sperate the dates and csv files? cuz that would totally make it perfect.

Comment: Umm separate for example?

Comment: These are 5 csv files, so like this http://prntscr.com/6cxqk9 but then the dates will be there and the table row removed? I dont know if I explain it right but.